# The use of "for" with the verb "to crave"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

My gut feeling tells me one says "I crave chocolate" and not "I crave for chocolate". This was confirmed for example at [this forum discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1610582).

However, google also showed me the sentence "I crave for you" was in fact used in [this pop song](http://www.metrolyrics.com/i-crave-for-you-lyrics-of-the-wand-and-the-moon.html)!

Could someone please clarify which use is correct? Should one say "I crave chocolate" or "I crave for chocolate", or are both equally fine? Thanks a lot!

By the way, I am aware that "i have a craving for chocolate" is correct English (and am not a native speaker).

Comment: It was used in the 19th century; [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=5TkBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA504&dq=%22craved+for+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YvMVVMP2BIOhyASd24DYDQ&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22craved%20for%20the%22&f=false) is an issue of Charles Dickens' magazine with *His very soul craved for the gorgeous and impossible beauty …* And the OED has *craved for* attested since the 15th century (although the transitive usage seems to predate the intransitive).

Comment: It's difficult to judge using [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=craved+love%2Ccraved+for+love%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ccraved+for+love%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccraved%20love%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraved%20for%20love%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccraved%20for%20love%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) because of the number of false positives, but it looks like the usage of *craved for* has been steadily decreasing for the last 100 years. It sounds ungrammatical to me, but there are apparently still people who use it.

Comment: Genref. [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crave): crave vb
1. (when: intr, foll by for or after) to desire intensely; long (for)
2. (tr) to need greatly or urgently
3. (tr) to beg or plead for

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth ! But this "when" makes me doubt: is this saying that *whenever* crave is used intransitively, it is followed by "for" or "after"? But one could still use the verb transitively and use it as in meaning 1, to desire intensely? Or does this mean that whenever usage 1 is meant, the verb should be used intransitively?

Comment: Your first explanation; AHDEL is better than Collins with the transitive sense: 1. To have an intense desire for.

Comment: _For_ is necessary with the noun _craving_ (as in _a craving for chocolate and pickles_), but not for the verb _crave_ (as in _he craves chocolate_). However, it may be that the noun construction is more common and possibly influenced the verb construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds horribly odd to my ears (probably worth noting the group in that song is not native-English speaking).  *Crave* is (virtually) always a transitive verb in Modern English and needs to have an object.  The reason that the noun form works with *for* is that nouns will need prepositions to add in objects like that.  For example, *The company prints **Ø** the books* versus *There's a new printing **of** the books*.

As Peter Shore points out, the OED recognizes its use, but its usage is quite rare these days.  Searching around with some other phrases besides *I crave for* (since that's taken up by song lyrics), almost every instance of *crave for* sounded off to my modern ears *except* when *for* was the head of a clause or when the object craved is intended for someone else:

- Someone craves for someone else something.

  - *in other words:* Someone craves something for someone else.
- I crave for someone to do something.

  - *but not* *I crave someone to do something.

For examples of these you've got *Rest he craves for you in His bosom* <sup>[1](http://www.poetrysoup.com/poems/short/craves)</sup>
 - *…he craves for you to f— off* <sup>[2](https://twitter.com/cannyswim/status/478174830022639616)</sup>

So you *can* use it as it's certainly been used that way, but recognize it will come off as antiquated or weird to most people.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Ghostwriter it's been more than 20 years and I'm 56. I never use in my life for any characters "crave for something". In music lyrics and poetry, all is allowed. It's called poetic license. The right way for saying that, or expressing it within a writing is "crave something". The "TO" is implicit.