# Nuances for 'craving'

Tags: nuance

Consider the following sentences:

> 1a) I **crave** solitude.
>
> 1b) I **crave for** solitude.
>
> 2a) I miss home-cooked food. I **crave** it.
>
> 2b) I miss home-cooked food. I **crave for** it.

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/crave) lists both forms under a single entry.

Are the meanings identical? Or does the preposition `for` add a nuance? For some reason, (1a) and (2b) sound more idiomatic than their counterparts to me, but I could be wrong.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crave%20it%2C%20crave%20for%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrave%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrave%20for%20it%3B%2Cc0) shows `crave it` winning over `crave for it`

---

Also, instead of the continuous construction of the verb `crave`, the noun `craving` sounds more idiomatic. As in

> 3a) **I'm craving** for some chocolate. (or **I'm craving** some chocolate?)
>
> 3b) **I have a craving** for some chocolate.

Is (3a) correct, or is `crave` a [stative verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb) like `need`(and therefore can't be used like this)?

If (3a) is correct, are (3a) and (3b) identical in meaning, or is there a nuance here too?

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m%20craving%2CI%20have%20a%20craving&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20craving%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20a%20craving%3B%2Cc0) shows `I have a craving` to be more common, but `I'm craving` is gaining popularity.

Does anyone know the correct use cases of these three forms of expressing a craving?

Comment: In AmE we usually say "I crave [something]" and "I have a craving for [something]"; we seldom if ever say "I crave for [something]." Of the first two, the second is much more likely to be heard.

Comment: It's news to me that "I crave for" is possible at all. I would have said that it's not English, period. And I would say, "I'm dying for a drink"; "crave" here feels unidiomatic. Brits also say, "I could murder a good cup of tea right now".

Comment: @DavidPugh: So you're saying in US, they're more likely to say (2a) than (2b)?

Comment: I can picture some Lothario in a purple romance novel saying "*But Emily, I **crave for** your love!*".

Comment: Related: [***The use of "for" with the verb "to crave"***](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196399/the-use-of-for-with-the-verb-to-crave)

Comment: @Robusto; Would you say "I crave solitude" or "I have a craving for solitude"?

Comment: @Area: I would, like Greta Garbo, simply say "I want to be alone."

Comment: @Area: I remain just as astonished as this morning at all those who think we can say "I crave for" anything. Reading Josh's link, I see that it is possible but on the verge of extinction. BTW Dan's Lothario is surely some wop, isn't he? So he's bound to get it wrong, in between ruining Emily and twirling his moustachios....

Comment: @DavidPugh: That's the magic of EL&U. You learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @Area: Since you were interested, at the peril of the Blackboard Monitors I can reveal that I've escaped the continent where stuff doesn't work. Am at the foot of the Eiger.

Comment: @DavidPugh: Well I do hope you reach your destination, if there is one!

Comment: @Area: Not the North Wall of the Eiger, anyway......

Comment: @DavidPugh: Good to see there still are some watchers on the Wall. In the North. If you stop by Winterfell, say hi to old Ned.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked everywhere and I can't find a solid answer for this. It comes down to preference, but in this case it is far more common that `crave` is left by itself (in any tense or construction) simply because of evolving dialects/tradition.

These are the more common statements:

> 1a) I **crave** solitude.
>   2a) I miss home-cooked food. I **crave** it.
>   3a) I'm **craving** a drink.

It's good to keep in mind, though, that the practice of adding on to the word in question (1b, 2b, 3b) only started to appear not too long ago. The second ngram you linked shows this.

Comment: So (3a) is OK? `crave` is NOT stative, then? Are you sure?

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction In this case, `crave` is not stative. It might be in other situations that I can't think up at the moment, but for our purposes, no.  It's good to note that all of the phrases you wrote mean the exact same thing. As I said, adding things on to the base word has just recently become a practice which means both practices came from the same place in some way.

Comment: @Adam: Is this the same process of "adding things onto the base word" that has Brits visiting people but Americans visiting _with_ them?

Comment: @DavidPugh It seems in that case that _visiting_ people and _visiting with_ people are both the exact same thing. So yes, I would say this is the same process although _visiting_ doesn't fall into the same ambiguity that _craving_ does. Statements using _visiting_ are much clearer than ones using _craving_ (which I guess is why OP asked the question).